# SpringBoot JPA relationsships - prevent creating new entity if object existing and instead return the object that already exists

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jpa, foreign-keys

I have a Customer entity built with a controller, service and repository logic.

And i also have an Address entity with nothing more than a simple POJO and @oneToMany annotation.

If i make two **POST** requests with *identical* address properties - how do i tell my application that if these address properties *already exist* in the database - *prevent* adding a new entity in the database but instead return the already existing one?

E.g. **POST** requests:

```json
// First request
{
    "name": "Foo",
    "contact": "123456",
    "email": "Foo@gmail.com",
    "address": {
        "street": "Wall street", 
        "postalCode": 10,
        "houseNo": "45",
        "city": "New York"
    }
}

// Second request
{
    "name": "Bar",
    "contact": "5321",
    "email": "Bar@gmail.com",
    "address": {
        "street": "Wall street", <----- same as first request
        "postalCode": 10, <----- same as first request
        "houseNo": "45", <----- same as first request
        "city": "New York" <----- same as first request
    }
}
```

This is the result when fetching all customers:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Foo",
        "contact": "123456",
        "email": "Foo@gmail.com",
        "address": {
            "id": 1,
            "street": "Wall street",
            "postalCode": 10,
            "houseNo": "45",
            "city": "New York"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Bar",
        "contact": "5321",
        "email": "Bar@gmail.com",
        "address": {
            "id": 2, <---------------- expect this ID to be 1 
            "street": "Wall street",
            "postalCode": 10,
            "houseNo": "45",
            "city": "New York"
        }
    }
]
```

Here is the necessary information (if) needed to help me proceed with my little project.

**Customer.java**

```java
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
@Entity
@Table
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "customer_sequence",
            sequenceName = "customer_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "customer_sequence"
    )
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String contact;
    private String email;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", nullable = false)
    private Address address;
    [...]
```

**Address.java**

```java
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
@Entity
@Table
public class Address {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "address_sequence",
            sequenceName = "address_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "address_sequence"
    )
    private Long id;
    private String street;
    private int postalCode;
    private String houseNo;
    private String city;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "address")
    private Set<Customer> customers;
    [...]
```

**CustomerController.java**

```java
//...
@PostMapping
    public void createCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
        customerService.createCustomer(customer);
    }

[...]
```

And the ***service*** that saves the customer to the DB:

```java
//...
public void createCustomer(Customer customer) {
        customerRepository.save(customer);
    }

[...]
```

Comment: in createCustomer could you invoke repository.save(customer) only if there is no customer with name, contact and email equal to the customer you get by parameter?

Comment: Lets say i did that - then i wouldnt be able to save customer even if the address already exists in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to NOT create duplicated addresses by doing some small changes.

First og foremost I autogenerated **equals()** inside my Address class:

```java
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Address address = (Address) o;
        return postalCode == address.postalCode && street.equals(address.street) && houseNo.equals(address.houseNo) && city.equals(address.city);
    }
```

In my service where i create the customer I've implemented this code to check if any customer has the the same address as the new customer:

```java
public void createCustomer(Customer customer) {
        Optional<Customer> customerWithExistingAddress = customerRepository.findAll()
                .stream()
                .filter(x -> x.getAddress().equals(customer.getAddress()))
                .findFirst();

        customerWithExistingAddress.ifPresent(c -> customer.setAddress(c.getAddress()));

        customerRepository.save(customer);
    }
```

Now it doesn't create a new entity if already exists.

Comment: it is unlikely someone would find your question here. If you have different question which is not related to original question then create new question.

Comment: You are probably right. This answer only fixed a part of the problem but its not exactly related to the original question any more.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hash with your address parameters and keep that like;

```
"street": "Wall street",
"postalCode": 10,
"houseNo": "45",
"city": "New York"
"uid": "3rn3u924917vt8r78b17vxver"
```

When you get a new address you can create a hash with it and get the address with that hash. If any address exists with that hash, get that address and put it in your customer object and save.

Comment: Interesting approach though i have some doubts that this is a long term solution. Imagine i have the same issue for 20 other classes - then i would have to send an unique hash and do some validation for each request. This worries me